# Azure B2C with custom SAML2 policy and Sha256 as the signing algorithm

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, sustainsys-saml2

I am using Sustainsys package `Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2` to build a service provider web app in ASP.NET Core 3.1, which uses Azure B2C as the identity provider using `SAML2`. I have the following issue:

1. If I use `Sha1` as the signing algorithm, using the option `MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm`, then an exception is thrown by `CryptoConfig.CreateFromName` because that method does not know the `Sha1` algorithm.
2. If I use `Sha256` as the signing algorithm then Azure B2C signs the response with `Sha1` even though I have specified `<Item Key="XmlSignatureAlgorithm">Sha256</Item>` in the `RelyingParty` of my custom policy. **I should note that this seems to only happen when the service provider starts the single logout flow.** The login flow completes without issues and there the signing algorithm is `Sha256`. Here is my RelyingParty section:

```
 <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
       <Metadata>
        <Item Key="XmlSignatureAlgorithm">Sha256</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="objectId" ExcludeAsClaim="true"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

Furthermore, the metadata of Azure B2C uses `Sha256` as the signature and digest method. Here is the relevant section:

```
<SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
    <Reference URI="...">
        <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
        <InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="saml samlp xenc xs"/>
        </Transform>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
    </Reference>
</SignedInfo>
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to add `<Item Key="XmlSignatureAlgorithm">Sha256</Item>` to the tehcnical profile as well (in addition to it being part of RelyingParty as shown above). This solves the issue that I had with single logout.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="Saml2AssertionIssuer">
  <Protocol Name="None"/>
  <OutputTokenFormat>SAML2</OutputTokenFormat>
  <Metadata>    
    <Item Key="XmlSignatureAlgorithm">Sha256</Item>
  </Metadata>
</TechnicalProfile>
```